# Integration by parts in dimensional regularisation

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

I have a question concerning integration by parts identities in dimensional regularisation. Appearently, almost every textbook about dimensional regularisation claims that 
$$\int d^Dl_1...d^Dl_L \frac{d}{dl_i^\mu}  \frac{v_i^\mu N}{\rho_1...\rho_n}=0$$
is zero. (we consider a Feynman-integral in momentum space with loop momenta $l_1,...,l_L$ and propagators $\rho_1,...,\rho_n$ in $D$ dimensions.). This is rather obvious if the integrand vanishes faster then $1/l_j^D$ for each $j$, however, it also seems to be true if that is not the case.
Unfortunately, no textbook I found really proves this identity. So, why do the boundary terms of this integral vanish even when the integral is not convergent? And in which book or paper can I find a rigorous proof?

Edit: I think I found somewhat a solution, both in section 4.1 of Collins, Renormalisation and in section 7 of Peskin Schroeder:
In some low enough dimension, the integrand vanishes sufficiently fast at infinity, as
$d^Dl= S_{D-J} d^J_l l^{D-J}.$ Choosing $D$ small enough, (<0, if necessary) will make the integrand vanish sufficiently fast for large $l$ (infrared divergences are an issue, they should be regulated first) and hence by Stokes theorem, the identity is valid. Then the integral is redefined to be an analytic continuation in D of the integral calculated in low $D$ and hence a zero function is analytically continued to be zero everywhere. 
There is no conflict with the definition of the integral as the analytic continuation of the integral calculated in $D=4-\epsilon$, because the integrals can be expressed as $\Gamma$ functions in both cases and as this does not have branch cuts, there is a unique analytic continuation.